# Github group review

Tags: github

Can I get Github to automatically add a group of people to a review when a review is created?

Ideally, I would like to create a group of people, and be able to merge only if at least one person from that group has accepted the change.

The group of people would be SMEs for that area. Other reviewers can comment and accept, but the PR can only be merged if at least one of the SMEs has accepted the change.

Is it possible to do it in Github without using hooks?

Comment: The solution proposed (CODEOWERS) works well in GitHub, but as of this writing, it is currently not available for GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: Sorry about that! But while you might not be able to configure automated review requests to the granularity that a `CODEOWNERS` file could do, you can still have "required reviews" using protected branches, which are available in Github Enterprise 2.8+. It's a bit more limited than what `CODEOWNERS` can do, but it might help you out here. See the comments in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45808270/5099203) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you can do all of this without webhooks!

### Approval Groups

For the question of setting up "approval groups", you can use a [`CODEOWNERS`](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/) file to set this up.

From [the Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/) (emphasis mine):

> *Use a CODEOWNERS file to define individuals or teams that are responsible for code in a repository.*
>
> **Code owners are automatically requested for review** when someone opens a pull request that modifies code that they own. When someone with admin permissions has enabled required reviews, they can optionally require approval from a code owner.

The format for a `CODEOWNERS` file is similar to that of a `.gitignore`, but with Github usernames next to each of your scopes. Scopes are defined using the same rules as a `.gitignore` file.

(See the end of this answer for an example `CODEOWNERS` file.)

### Required Reviews

If you [setup protected branches in your Github repository](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/), you can also enable [required reviews](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/).

From [the Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/) (emphasis mine, again):

> Repository administrators can require that all pull requests **receive at least one approved review from someone with write or admin permissions or from a designated code owner** before they're merged into a protected branch.
>
> When required reviews are enabled, anyone with access to the repository can approve changes in a pull request. However, to merge your pull request you need someone who has write or admin permissions in the repository to approve your pull request's changes in their review. If review is required from a designated code owner and the pull request affects code that has a designated owner, approval from that owner is required.

---

#### Example CODEOWNERS file (from [the Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/#codeowners-file-example)):

```
# This is a comment.

# These owners will be the default owners for everything in
# the repo. Unless a later match takes precedence,
# @global-owner1 and @global-owner2 will be requested for
# review when someone opens a pull request.
*       @global-owner1 @global-owner2

# Order is important; the last matching pattern takes the most
# precedence. When someone opens a pull request that only
# modifies JS files, only @js-owner and not the global
# owner(s) will be requested for a review.
*.js    @js-owner

# You can also use email addresses if you prefer. They'll be
# used to look up users just like we do for commit author
# emails.
*.go docs@example.com

# In this example, @doctocat owns any files in the build/logs
# directory at the root of the repository and any of its
# subdirectories.
/build/logs/ @doctocat

# The `docs/*` pattern will match files like
# `docs/getting-started.md` but not further nested files like
# `docs/build-app/troubleshooting.md`.
docs/*  docs@example.com

# In this example, @octocat owns any file in an apps directory
# anywhere in your repository.
apps/ @octocat

# In this example, @doctocat owns any file in the `/docs`
# directory in the root of your repository.
/docs/ @doctocat
```

Comment: CODEOWNERS only works in GitHub. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in GitHub Enterprise (which I am using).

Comment: @AlexandreSantos Ah, that's unfortunate. While you might not be able to configure them to the granularity that a `CODEOWNERS` file could do, you can still have "required reviews" using [protected branches](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.10/user/articles/configuring-protected-branches/), which are available in Github Enterprise 2.8+.

Comment: See [the Github docs on required reviews in Github Enterprise](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.10/user/articles/about-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/) for more information: _"Repository administrators can require that all pull requests receive at least one approved review from someone with write or admin permissions before they're merged into a protected branch."_

Comment: This, unfortunately, won't automatically request users for review though—it'll just prevent a pull request from being merged without at least one approved review from someone with **write** or **admin** permissions on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

stumbled upon this when last week when I was onboarding on a new team and had this issue.

Made a simple chrome extension to create/save lists of usernames and bulk-add these lists as reviewers on my currently open PR

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-reviewer-groups/mmgjipidkhkfimmfgcgklooinlcfonah?hl=en&authuser=0

It's open source too, so feel free to try improving it.